# Python - Grabbing Permutation Importance From OLS Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, regression

As the title states, I'm trying to grab permutation importance for the features in my OLS model, but am getting this:

TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper object at 0x7fc52c9d5e0> was passed

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv(r'my_file')

X = df.drop(my dependent variable)
y = df[my dependent variable)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

model - sm.OLS(y_train, X_train).fit()
print(model.summary())

score = permuation_importance(model, X_train, y_train, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error')

importance = score.importances_mean

for i,v in enumerate(importance):
   print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
```

I have a feeling it's because I'm using a model not from sklearn, so was wondering if there's a way I can grab feature metrics from my OLS model? Thank you!!

Comment: One point: permutation importance needs to be passed a held out set (X_test, y_test) to give reliable (generalizable) results.

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are passing the regression results, rather than the fitted model, to the `permutation_importance` method. To get rid of this error, do the following:

```
model = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
score = permuation_importance(model, X_test, y_test, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error')
```

Here, `model` is of type `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS`, which implements the `.fit()` method. However, `results` is of type `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper`, which does not implement `.fit()`. The first argument passed to the `permutation_importance` method needs to be of a type for which the `.fit()` method is defined.

That being said, just because the model you pass to it implements `.fit()`, it doesn't necessarily mean that the model will be supported by sklearn. I recommend doing either one of the following:

### Option 1

Use sklearn's `LinearRegression`, rather than statsmodel's `OLS`. The former is definitely supported with sklearn's `permutation_importance` method. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

### Option 2

Assuming your data has been scaled appropriately, you can use the model coefficients as a measure of feature importance.

```
feature_importances = abs(results.params)
print(feature_importances.sort_values(ascending=False))
```